# Landscape Script timed out while executing bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, ssh, error-handling, landscape

I'm new to the bash script. Running a bash script to send a list of packages through a file to client machines. But it gives me the error as "Script timed out while executing."

Here is the code for the same.

#!/bin/bash
#Script to write the output into a file

#Create output file, override if already present
output=output_file.sh

sudo -S chmod u+w+x output_file.sh

#Write data to a file
echo "accountsservice" >> output _file.sh
echo "acl" >> output _file.sh
echo "acpi-support" >> output _file.sh
echo "acpid" >> output _file.sh

arp -ni eth0 | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}'

“remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal”: true,
“remote.SSH.useLocalServer”: false,

#Checking the content of the file
gedit output_file.sh

cat output_file.sh

fi

---

PLease help me in this regard.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's ignore the fact that your script is likely incomplete (hinted by the trailing `fi` without a starting `if;then`).

First, I would make sure that what you run does not block for input. (e.g. sudo, gedit).

Second, there is a time limit setting in landscape when editing scripts, as is visible in the [documentation](https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/user-guide/ch06.html#idm46604571393248). If your script runs for longer than 5 minutes, you may have to increase the timeout. You could also run as a specific user,